# Update join tables having max date sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, sql-update, having-clause

I am trying to update V.PUR_UNIT from PO_VEND_ITEM to equal the value of R.RECVD_UNIT from PO_RECVR_HIST_LIN but I want to select the R.RECVD_UNIT for the last date received ONLY
I have created the script below but still getting error

```
Update
PO_VEND_ITEM
Set
V.PUR_UNIT = R.RECVD_UNIT
FROM
PO_RECVR_HIST_LIN R

INNER JOIN
PO_VEND_ITEM V

ON
V.ITEM_NO = R.ITEM_NO

GROUP BY
V.PUR_UNIT,
V.ITEM_NO


HAVING
R.RECVR_DAT = MAX(R.RECVR_DAT)
```

Any advise please

Comment: Any help on this issue please

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL gives a table and alias, you need to use the alias, not the table name everywhere else, so the update should be UPDATE V, not UPDATE PO_VEND_ITEM.

In any case, that still won't fix your problem. You can't update an aggregated query - the whole point of aggregation is that it group rows together, and so is no longer linked the the original rows - it doesn't know which rows to update.

UPDATED BELOW, REMOVED INCORRECT DATA.

Where you want to sort by one column, but use a different column, aggregates are not usually going to work. Instead, in a subquery, sort the data you need to use by giving it a row number, then join to only row 1 - that is the row that has the data you want. This will only update the PO_VEND_ITEM rows where there are any matching PO_RECVR_HIST_LIN rows - if you want to update them all, then change the inner join to a left outer join and any with no matching rows will be set to NULL.

```
UPDATE V SET PUR_UNIT = R.QTY_UNIT
FROM PO_VEND_ITEM V
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ITEM_NO, QTY_UNIT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTION BY ITEM_NO ORDER BY RECVR_DAT DESC) RowNo
        FROM PO_RECVR_HIST_LIN
        ) R ON R.ITEM_NO = V.ITEM_NO AND R.RowNo = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you but It does not looks it work. I want PUT_UNIT = QTY_UNIT where RECVR_DAT = MAX(RECVR_DAT). I have changed the code to the following but still not working correctly UPDATE V SET PUR_UNIT = R.QTY_UNIT
FROM PO_VEND_ITEM V
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ITEM_NO, QTY_UNIT, MAX(RECVR_DAT) AS MAXDATE
        FROM PO_RECVR_HIST_LIN
        WHERE ITEM_NO = '300011'
        GROUP BY ITEM_NO, QTY_UNIT
        ) R ON R.ITEM_NO = V.ITEM_NO;

Comment: Sorry, I misread your problem. I think this is what you need.

Comment: No problem DancingFool Thank you for your great help